# What is the white stuff emerging from a hole on the surface of Mars?

Tags: mars, curiosity, geology

> **Edit:** It can almost certainly be excluded that the white spot was caused by [Curiosity's ChemCam's laser](https://nasa.gov/jpl/msl/laser-flash-20140716), because it doesn't make sense that the laser was used at that time without taking images with ChemCam.
>   The only images captured by ChemCam on sol 550 were taken at least **1 hour before** and at least **3 hours after** the white stuff appeared on the surface of Mars, so it's highly unlikely that when that happened the laser was used.

[image: the hole without the white stuff.[1]]

The image above was captured by the Mars Hand Lens Imager (MAHLI) on sol 550 (february 22, 2014).

4 minutes later, white stuff seems to have emerged from one of the holes on that image, shown in the image below.

[image: the same hole with the white stuff.[2]]

The pictures above are part of a sequence of raw images shown on the [mars.nasa.gov site](https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/multimedia/raw-images/). 6 images captured in 30 sec. show this white stuff, after that another feature was imaged.

What could this be ?

Comment: To me it looks like either a fault with the photograph or glare. I don't see the white patch emerging from the hole but on the surface of the rock to one side of the hole.

Comment: To me it looks a *very much* like vapor that has come out of the hole, hit a colder environment and transitioned from vapor to solid phase as ice. Having grown up in a place with plenty of sub-zero (0°F) mornings and seen my breath and other moist vapors turn to ice on windows and other surfaces, it certainly looks familiar to me. But that doesn't mean necessarily that that is what has actually happened here.

Comment: @Fred Yes, there's no proof that it emerged from the hole. Maybe white powder falling from the turret ?

Comment: AAACHOOOOO!!!!!

Comment: @Sean Is that the chemical formula of the white stuff ?

Comment: @uhoh Reading your description i do remember also frozen flowers on a window and even frost on the blanket ! Having read the answer below i think its not vapor from the hole but maybe ice in the soil vaporized by the laser ?

Comment: ya, I think so too. I just meant that I agree; it does make me wonder (momentarily at least) if something is coming out of the hole and then freezing.

Comment: @uhoh Don't you think the answer below is not correct ?  The white spot that is caused by the laser doesn't last, does it ?

Comment: @Conelisinspace I just don't know. If I had some reason to think it was not correct I would have commented, and I think others would do so as well.

Comment: @uhoh  You can see clearly on the video that the laser is only on for maybe 10 seconds , causing dust but not leaving a white spot.

Comment: @Conelisinspace I can not understand the video at all, and I don't have anything else to contribute to this topic at this time.

Answer (score 9):

That's almost certainly ChemCam's laser vaporizing some rock for its spectrometer. You can see similar white spots in this video:

The laser fires in short pulses 10 times a second, and there's gaps between the video frames captured by MAHLI. The two are not synchronized and only sometimes align, allowing MAHLI to see the laser. Other times, MAHLI only captures the time between pulses and things like dust being kicked around.

It's clearly not a physical material on the rock, as this image taken at 08:09:22 UTC shows the spot:

https://mars.nasa.gov/raw_images/137423/?site=msl

While this one taken a few minutes later at 08:14:17 UTC does not:

https://mars.nasa.gov/raw_images/137463/?site=msl

The descriptions at those links refer to a multi-image focus merge process which will increase the odds of the laser spot being caught if the laser is on.

Comment: The white spots are similar, but 5 more images are captured within half a minute that show the same spot, while the spot from the  vaporizing rock disappears again, doesn't it ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're discounting the possibility that they're continuing to use ChemCam's laser while taking those images.

Comment: The firing was 10 times a sec. *for 10 sec*.

Comment: In that specific video, yes. So?

Comment: The times you mention in your answer are those when the merging was done with 2 to 8 images. You have to mention the times of each single image. Those single images are also shown farther on in the sequence of that sol.

Comment: Those single images show that the white spot lasted at least 30 sec, so longer than the  normal duration of 10 sec. of the firing. On the raw images of sol 550 if found  only 4 Chemcam images taken at least one hour before the white spot emerged.

Comment: A video of it firing for 10 s does not mean that is the "normal" operation or that it couldn't be fired multiple times. There is nothing at all strange about them having it active during each of those 5 images.

Comment: I don't know but i think it takes to much energy. The other argument, that it doesn't make sense to fire the laser when no ChemCam images are taken, stays.

Comment: It does not "take too much energy" to fire the laser. It only took about 16 months to fire it 100000 times. And it makes perfect sense not to waste bandwidth on unneeded ChemCam images. The laser is for use with the spectrometer. The imager is just to provide context for the spectrometer readings, if the ChemCam hasn't been retargeted and the sample hasn't shifted there's no point in taking more images with it.

Comment: O.k. you win !  But couldn't  the white stuff been released by the firing of the laser on the rock ?